# Rails - Generating multiple pages dynamically based on database records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app and I need to loop through records in a database and match them with records in the same database then render a page with content that is based on the words present in the URL.

So imagine we have this database:

```
1 Basketball
2 Soccer
3 Baseball
4 Swimming
```

I need to build a function that generates a page for each:

```
domain.com/basketball-soccer
domain.com/basketball-baseball
domain.com/basketball-swimming
domain.com/soccer-baseball
domain.com/soccer-swimming
domain.com/baseball-swimming
```

This shouldn't generate pages for basketball-basketball, etc. and if it generates a page for basketball-soccer, page for soccer-basketball

also a page like domain.com/basketball-cricket because cricket isn't listed in the database

Example of how the content should display on each page:
This page is for a Basketball / Soccer match.

Looking for suggestions or resources on getting started with this. I'm not sure if it's possible to generate pages on the fly like this. I don't want to build each of these pages individually.

Comment: You can use a wildcard type of url and check within your controller whether that url is valid. In your case, you can split `params[:combination]` by '-' in your controller, then check within the model whether both params (e.g., 'basketball' and 'soccer') exist. Semi-static page can then be generated.
Take a look at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages
edit: looks like @ajeferson got the same thing for ya

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like having a regex in your routes. Put this in your `routes.rb`:

```
match '/:regex', to: 'your_controller#your_action', constraints: {regex: /[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+?/}, via: :get
```

Then in your controller, you will get a param called `regex`, which you can access with `params[:regex]` and handle properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a wildcard (catch all) route, and then handle all the logic inside the controller. For example:

```
# routes.rb
# put this as the last route in the file
get '*url_pair', to: 'examples#show'

# examples_controller.rb
def show
  # get both values into an array, and sort into alphabetical order
  # (so pages URL pairings are always consistent)
  names = params[:url_pair].split('-').sort

  # show 404 not found if the names are the same
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if names.uniq.count == 1

  # see if they are valid on the database. Note the use of find_by!,
  # so if either one or both don't exist, a RecordNotFound error will be raised,
  # resulting in a 404 not found page
  @activities = names.each { |n| ActivitiesModel.find_by!(name: n) }

  # if you've reached here, then we get to view rendering.
  # @activities is available to map up the view
end
```

---

If you need to create a sitemap, or have a list of the valid pages - this will get you an array with all the valid pairings:

```
# you could also load these from the DB
# e.g. Model.pluck(:name)
values = ["basketball", "soccer", "baseball", "swimming"]

values.combination(2).to_a.map(&:sort)
# => [["basketball", "soccer"], ["baseball", "basketball"], ["basketball", "swimming"], ["baseball", "soccer"], ["soccer", "swimming"], ["baseball", "swimming"]]
```

Comment: Wow, this is perfect Exactly what I was looking for. Quick question. The `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if names.uniq == 1` doesn't prevent same match pairs from rendering. Do you know why? I'm not familiar with this method

Comment: I figured it out— needs to be `names.uniq.count` in order to work

Comment: @user3006927: yup, you're right. I've updated the answer to reflect that now.